# Redirect my Database query output to a text file rather than the Shell in Python/sqlite3

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have several databases that at the moment i can call in my program, and the data i request is shown in the shell, but i want this data to go to a text file instead. Ideas? here is an extract of my code at the moment;

```
    #Pull important data from SMS
    def texts():
     connection = sqlite3.connect("mmssms.db")
     cursor = connection.cursor()

     cursor.execute("SELECT address, body, date FROM sms") 
     print("Text Messages")
     result = cursor.fetchall() 
     for f in result:
         print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this data to go to a text file, simply write the data in the result variable to a file. You can use the following syntax to write data to a file:

```
fout = open('write_to_this_file.txt', 'w')
line1 = 'This is a line that is being written to a file')
fout.write(line1)
fout.close()
```

So, you would need to format your data into lines of text and then write and then write the lines to the file.